# Why does it take more than ten minutes to deploy a cordova app on android device?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm literally considering abandoning phone-gap/cordova just because simply deploying on an android device for development can take more than ten minutes!!   If all that is changing is some of the web-view content, and not any  android classes, why oh why does it sit for 3 or 4 minutes doing seemingly nothing, then recompiling the app before pushing it onto the device.  I can build a native Android apk in about 30 seconds or less and then install it with adb install command.  and that is with native java android code that is churning.   Is there a better way to make changes to the static web content and get it the APK built and on the device than:

'cordova run android'

It makes no sense...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PhoneGap Developer app.  You can test/iterate immediately on file changes, without recompilation.  Just recompile when you want to push it to the app store.  http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/23/phonegap-developer-app/

It doesn't normally take that long unless you are packaging a TON of assets.  Do you have lots of large images in there?